# calculating mean for two columns of response variables at once

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze a dataset where there are two response variables X and Y with two grouping variables Treatment and Rep:

```
tribble(
    ~Treatment, ~Rep, ~X,   ~Y
    , "N1", 1, 10.18, 14.38
    , "N1", 2, 13.53, 14.38
    , "N2", 1, 15.34, 18.28
    , "N2", 2, 10.4,  7.14
    , "N3", 1, 8.57,  22.57
    , "N3", 2, 13.95, 19.9
    , "N4", 1, 16.69, NA
    , "N4", 2, 14.33, 9.32
    , "N5", 1, NA,    NA
    , "N5", 2, 15.74, 15.39
)
```

I want to calculate mean, sd and se values for each treatment for each response variable. Then I want to make a line plot with Treatment on x-axis; and two lines each for X and Y with confidence interval error bars.

I have used this to calculate using summarise_at:

```
df<-Data1 %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), list(mean = ~mean(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                         sd = ~sd(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE),
                                         se= ~sd(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n()))) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(mean:se), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in if (trim > 0 && n) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am not sure if I can put two variables this way for summarise_at. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `sd()` takes one argument - what is `sd(X,Y)` supposed to do?

Comment: I wanted to calculate mean, sd and se for both X and Y. it gives an error even if I put only one argument.

Comment: Try this as a first step `Data1 %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>%   
  summarise_at(vars(X, Y), list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                sd = ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
                                se= ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))`. The functions need only one argument and `.x` will first take the `X` values and then the `Y` values, as you are focusing on those two columns.

Comment: ...also, your example dataset is not helping much, as you have one value for each `Treatment` and `Rep` pair. :) It would be much better to provide a few values for 2-3 unique pairs, so `mean` and `sd` could make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
se <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)/sqrt(length(x))

df %>%
    group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(X,Y)
                 , list(sd = sd
                        , mean = mean
                        , se = se)
                 , na.rm = TRUE)

   Treatment   Rep  X_sd  Y_sd X_mean Y_mean  X_se  Y_se
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 N1            1    NA    NA  10.2   14.4     NA    NA
 2 N1            2    NA    NA  13.5   14.4     NA    NA
 3 N2            1    NA    NA  15.3   18.3     NA    NA
 4 N2            2    NA    NA  10.4    7.14    NA    NA
 5 N3            1    NA    NA   8.57  22.6     NA    NA
 6 N3            2    NA    NA  14.0   19.9     NA    NA
 7 N4            1    NA    NA  16.7  NaN       NA    NA
 8 N4            2    NA    NA  14.3    9.32    NA    NA
 9 N5            1    NA    NA NaN    NaN       NA    NA
10 N5            2    NA    NA  15.7   15.4     NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you, however, it is not giving the mean and other values.

Comment: Yes, it is giving the mean. See the edited answer with the output. It doesn't provide standard deviations as the groups have only 2 values, but that should be fine, if you have bigger groups.

Comment: It is not giving mean for each treatment over two reps. e.g. 11.85 for X_mean for N1.

Comment: Your code above doesn't say "over two reps", it says `group_by(Treatment, Rep)`.

Comment: So, if you remove `Rep` from the `group_by()` in my answer, you get that result. I can change that in the answer, but then you need the change it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a reproducible minimal example data set

```
df <- data.frame(Treatment = paste0("N", rep(1:5, each=2)),
                 Rep = c(1,2),
                 X = runif(10),
                 Y = runif(10))
```

2.A solution using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Treatment) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(),
            X_sd = sd(X, na.rm=FALSE),
            Y_sd = sd(Y, na.rm=FALSE),
            X_mean = mean(X, na.rm=FALSE),
            Y_mean = mean(Y, na.rm=FALSE),
            X_se = X_sd/sqrt(N),
            Y_se = Y_sd/sqrt(N)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(X_mean, Y_mean),
               names_to = "mean") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, value, color = mean, group=mean)) +
    geom_line()
```

## Edit:

```
result_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Treatment) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(),
            X_sd = sd(X, na.rm=FALSE),
            Y_sd = sd(Y, na.rm=FALSE),
            X_mean = mean(X, na.rm=FALSE),
            Y_mean = mean(Y, na.rm=FALSE),
            X_se = X_sd/sqrt(N),
            Y_se = Y_sd/sqrt(N)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(X_mean, Y_mean),
               names_to = "mean")

result_df

result_plot <- result_df %>%
ggplot(aes(Treatment, value, color = mean, group=mean)) +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I check the mean, sd and se values in a table form? Can you please tell how it is working.